# Margin top = 50% of element jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have X amount of divs, all set to a specific height and width. Within these is an image, all vary in size. I want to find the height of the image, divide it by 2 and set that as the margin top value so all images are in the centre if this makes sense? Ive tried making a fiddle only im unsure how to go about it...

http://jsfiddle.net/R8QUL/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.box img').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var parentHeight = $this.parent().height();
        var thisHeight = $this.height();
        var topmargin = (parentHeight - thisHeight) / 2;
        $this.css("margin-top", topmargin);
    });
})
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/R8QUL/6/

Comment: It may be worthy of note that `.innerHeight()` might work too, since this includes `padding`, and that is visually part of the interior of a box element. I'm imagining that this may be something that probably has to be considered as well, judging from what Liam appears to be trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var boxheight = $('.box').height();

    $('.box img').each(function(i){
            var topmargin = (boxheight - $(this).height()) / 2
            $(this).css("margin-top", topmargin);
   });



})
```

**live demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/R8QUL/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box img').each(function() {
       $(this).css("margin-top", $(this).parent().height()/2-$(this).height()/2);
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/R8QUL/8/)

Answer (score 1):

if you're interested in a pure css solution : http://jsfiddle.net/R8QUL/11/
just add

```
.box
    line-height: 225px;
}

.box img {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some images take a while to load, and thus have no width or height yet. To fix this problem you can use setTimeout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($('.box'), function(){
         centerImage($(this));
    });
});

function centerImage(box){
    var imgWidth = $(box).find('img').width();      
    var imgHeight = $(box).find('img').height();

    if(imgWidth > 0 && imgHeight > 0){
       $(box).find('img').css('margin-top', ($(box).height() - imgHeight)/2);
    } else {
       setTimeout(function(){ centerImage(box); }, 100);
    }       
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7EDSF/